# User ID not showing up in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, analytics

What can be the reason the `user_id` is `null` in BigQuery? Data from Analytics is sent to BigQuery but the `user_id` is not passed along. The `user_id` is sent to Google Analytics but what could be the reason it is not available in BigQuery?

Comment: Have you actually enabled it? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205850?hl=en

Comment: Yes we did have :)

Answer (score 4):

Confirmed by Google Analytics 360 support, the `userId` only have non-null values in BigQuery tables that are exported from User-ID enabled views in Google Analytics. For non-User-ID views, you only see `null` values for the `userId`column and you have to use a custom dimension to capture User Ids and query them in BigQuery.

In order to check which Google Analytics view you have linked to BigQuery, you can either look at the dataset ID in BigQuery (which is the same as the Analytics View ID) or directly the linked Google Analytics view in Admin > All Products [Property column] > BigQuery in the Google Analytics UI.

Comment: Then you are encouraged to pass it also as Custom Dimension, User or Session scope for example, and let the value undefined when the user is not recognized, to prevent erasing the value set in a previous hit

Answer (score 2):

I am operating under the assumption that this field is intentionally held out from all Google Analytics -> BigQuery extracts based on the following:

- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205850?hl=en#limits

  - Of particular note, the line "*The User ID value can not be queried as a dimension in reports in either the web interface or the APIs*". I take this to mean that it will never leave the confines of Google Analytics, including to BigQuery.
- I have not been able to get anything but `null` in my tables either.

Sorry I do not have better news for you!

Comment: The UserID can be exposed, but not as dimension.
You have a User Explorer report in the GUI https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6339208?hl=en where you can apply segments to show only the User behavior you are looking to analyze

And the User Activity Explorer 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/user-reporting