# How to get measurement protocol hit data in Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

We're trying to connect online and offline behaviour via `measurement protocol`.
It's been sent a hit to `Google Analytics` with the following parameters (among others):

```
eventCategory= offline_transaction  
source= store  
medium= offline
```

The data are correctly registered in `Google Analytics`, been available in Reporting section.

I'm trying to get them in `BigQuery` this way:

```
SELECT  
hits.eventInfo.eventCategory, trafficSource.source, trafficSource.medium  
FROM [XXX:YYY.ga_sessions_20160827]  
where hits.eventInfo.eventCategory="offline_transaction" 
and trafficSource.source="store" 
and trafficSource.medium="offline"
```

and the output is 'Query returned zero records'.

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong? Are available in BigQuery the data coming from Measurement Protocol?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what is happening is that the trafficSource.source/medium are being recorded at the session level and hits.eventCategory at the hit level, and thus they are never included in a single row together, so 0 rows match your query. Try something like the below:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(IF (hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "offline_transaction", hits.eventInfo.eventCategory,  NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS eventCategory, 
  SUM(IF (hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = "offline_transaction", 1,  NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS eventCnt,
  trafficSource.source, 
  trafficSource.medium  
FROM [XXX:YYY.ga_sessions_20160827]  
  where hits.eventInfo.eventCategory="offline_transaction" 
  and trafficSource.source="store" 
  and trafficSource.medium="offline"
```

This should give you a count of how many times that event occurred within that session. Without knowing more about your use case/what you want to pull out of the table, I don't know how else to help.

I've had to use the *aggregate_function() WITHIN RECORD* syntax frequently to deal with these types of issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @andre622. It doesn't work. Maybe the fact that the view linked to BigQuery project has UserId disabled has influence over this behaviour? (the hits are associated to an UserId value).

Comment: Ahhh yes; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832034/userid-not-showing-up-in-bigquery/39582376#39582376)  for further reading on the user ID. Spoiler alert: it is not exported to BigQuery from GA profiles.