# GA 360 export to Big Query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

We have just linked our GA360 account to BigQuery but we noticed from the docs that the userId doesn't get exported. This is really annoying as one of our main use case was to join the userId with our CRM system.

Why is Google not exporting the userId ? Is there workaround ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Try having a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832034/userid-not-showing-up-in-bigquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create a User level custom dimension and pass your user's ID into that as well.

There's no restriction on exporting your custom dimensions, and these are exported to BigQuery.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

> How User-ID works
>   User-ID enables the association of one or more sessions (and the activity within those sessions) with a unique and persistent ID that you send to Analytics.
>
> To implement User-ID, you must be able to generate your own unique IDs, consistently assign IDs to users, and include these IDs wherever you send data to Analytics.
>
> For example, you could send the unique IDs generated by your own authentication system to Analytics as values for User-ID. Any engagement, like link clicks and page or screen navigation, that happen while a unique ID is assigned can be sent to Analytics and connected via User-ID.
>
> In an Analytics implementation without the User-ID feature, a unique user is counted each time your content is accessed from a different device and each time there’s a new session. For example, a search on a phone one day, purchase on a laptop three days later, and request for customer service on a tablet a month after that are counted as three unique users in a standard Analytics implementation, even if all those actions took place while a user was signed in to an account. While you can collect data about each of those interactions and devices, you can’t determine their relevance to one another. You only see independent data points.
>
> When you implement User-ID, you can identify related actions and devices and connect these seemingly independent data points. That same search on a phone, purchase on a laptop, and re-engagement on a tablet that previously looked like three unrelated actions on unrelated devices can now be understood as one user’s interactions with your business.

From [Google analytics about the userid feature](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en) the user id is used in the background by google analytics to analyse your data.

If you want to analyse on the user id you can just add it as a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) you will then be able to see it.

Comment: I know how to set up userId in GA and what it means. Our issue is about export from GA360 to BigQuery. From the export doc (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7430726?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089), it explicitly says that the userId field will be unavailable. I am wondering why as this data is available at GA level.